# Add Array to Existing Object

Tags: php, arrays, json

This seems pretty easy, but I can't figure it out. I have an existing array of objects that was json_decoded. I need to iterate over those objects, append a new array to each, and then put the overall array back together. I can't get the new array to append in the correct place.

```
function appendToArray($arrayOfObjects) {

    $newArray = array();

    foreach ($arrayOfObjects as $object) {
        echo "<pre>".print_r($object, true)."</pre>";

        $newItems = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
        $moreItems = array('more1', 'more2', 'more3');

        $newObject = array();
        $newObject["newItems"] = $newItems;
        $newObject["moreItems"] = $moreItems;

        $rebuiltObject = array();
        array_push($rebuiltObject, $object);
        $rebuiltObject['new_stuff'] = $newObject;
        // $rebuiltObject[0]['new_stuff'] = $newObject;

        array_push($newArray, $newObject);
    }

     return $newArray;
}
```

Here is an example of one of the objects that I start with (after `json_decode` of course:

```
0 => stdClass Object
(
    [code] => some code
    [first_name] => First
    [last_name] => Last
    [urls] => stdClass Object
        (
            [news] => http://www.somesite.com/news
            [info] => http://www.somesite.com/info
        )

    [geo] => stdClass Object
        (
            [latitude] => 0.0
            [longitude] => 0.0
            [name] => building name
        )
)
```

When this is done, what I want is this:

```
0 => stdClass Object
(
    [code] => some code
    [first_name] => First
    [last_name] => Last
    [urls] => stdClass Object
        (
            [news] => http://www.somesite.com/news
            [info] => http://www.somesite.com/info
        )

    [geo] => stdClass Object
        (
            [latitude] => 0.0
            [longitude] => 0.0
            [name] => building name
        )
     [new_stuff] => Array
            (
                [newItems] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => item1
                        [1] => item2
                        [2] => item3
                    )

                [moreItems] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => more1
                        [1] => more2
                        [2] => more3
                    )

            )
)
```

But what I get is this:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
(
    [code] => some code
    [first_name] => First
    [last_name] => Last
    [urls] => stdClass Object
        (
            [news] => http://www.somesite.com/news
            [info] => http://www.somesite.com/info
        )

    [geo] => stdClass Object
        (
            [latitude] => 0.0
            [longitude] => 0.0
            [name] => building name
        )
),
[new_stuff] => Array
            (
                [newItems] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => item1
                        [1] => item2
                        [2] => item3
                    )

                [moreItems] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => more1
                        [1] => more2
                        [2] => more3
                    )

            )

    )
```

Notice how `[new_stuff]` is outside of the original object. I need to get it inside. Everything else I've tried crashes and I'm totally out of ideas. Can anyone see how I can do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You solution is one string:

```
$object->new_stuff = $newObject;
```

because every `$object` is **object** and not **array**. And adding new property to object is done via `->` and not with `[]`.

Full code:

```
function appendToArray($arrayOfObjects) {

    foreach ($arrayOfObjects as $object) {
        echo "<pre>".print_r($object, true)."</pre>";

        $newItems = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
        $moreItems = array('more1', 'more2', 'more3');

        $newObject = array();
        $newObject["newItems"] = $newItems;
        $newObject["moreItems"] = $moreItems;

        $object->new_stuff = $newObject;
    }

    return $arrayOfObjects;
}
```

Comment: I knew the answer was right in front of me. I had tried adding it to `$object` but couldn't make it work. I think I tried everything but that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can just [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and change the object inplace:

```
array_walk($arrayOfObjects, function(&$item) {
   $item->new_stuff = ["newItems" => ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], etc];
});
```